# Alternate methods to understand an integral.

Tags: calculus, integration, soft-question

An Integral of a function $f(x)$ is explained as the limit of sum of areas of the rectangles under the curve (Riemann's Sum) which are of infinitesimal thickness $dx$.
I wanted to know if there is any other alternate approach to understand an integral that can explain how it gives us the area under the curve without using hard to digest ideas like limits and infinitely thin rectangles? I really couldn't find anything much helpful over the internet.

Comment: @SineoftheTime If someone finds Riemann integration difficult to understand, then Lebesgue integration is not an approachable alternative

Comment: Here's a question that might help you get started: How can you define precisely what the area under a curve is?

Comment: @Aniket What exactly do you mean by "how it gives the area under the curve"? In a sense, the integral of the function is the (signed) area under that function's curve, so of course it "gives" the area under the curve. Is the question here how the usual process of computing an integral (using antiderivatives) produces the correct answer?

Comment: You could define it as the least upper bound of the area of all step functions that fit under the function. This still involves arbitrarily thin rectangles, though, since a step function can have any number of steps.

Comment: No there aren't really any other methods other than using "limits and infinitely thin rectangles". Honestly if you find those ideas hard to grasp you should go back to them, because there are esential to whole calculus. Once you understand those you could, instead of Riemman sums, take a look at Darboux sums it might make it easier for you.

Comment: @GauravChandan The way it was explained to me was using some help of physics. We take a straight thin rod which can move in 2D with the only constraint being its orientation remains constant. In case of any motion of the rod, the area swept by it is given by length of rod multiplied by the vertical component of distance traveled. As horizontal component of motion will add no area.(Here 'horizontal' is the direction along the length of rod)

Comment: @BenGrossmann I understand the general approach of integration, which is in essence of making closer and closer approximation of the Riemann sum, and reducing the error infinitesimally. But what irks me about the approach is, there is no actual alternative (for example cutting and rearranging parallelograms to form rectangles) which saves the trouble of dealing with infinity.

Comment: How would rearranging parallelograms save you the trouble of dealing with infinity? For instance, how would parallelograms help you compute 
$$
\int_0^1 3x^2\,dx?
$$

Comment: @BenGrossmann What I stated was an example of different approaches to find area when you have simple polygons. When we rearrange triangles, the pieces fit together because we don't have to deal with concavity or convexity of a function. I tried an integral of $x^2$ before posting the question, bust most I could conclude was average cross sectional length of parabola(bounded with y-axis) was twice the cross sectional length of region bounded by parabola and x-axis.(Cross sectional  lengths along direction of Yaxis). I used limits & the sum of series of squares,but it boils down to same concept.

Comment: @Aniket I understand now. In any case, there really is no alternative to integration that avoids limits/infinitesimals but calculates area with the same amount of versatility

Comment: If there is one, I've never heard of it.  I'm 99% certain that if there is any other way to understand how the area under the curve is the limit of Riemann sums, is the net change in the antiderivative, it will be harder to understand than the traditional explanations in terms of limits or infinitesimals.

Comment: @Addem I think I know one approach for integral of $y=x^2$. Take a graph of $y=x$ in x-y plane, take any point $(a,a)$ on line $y=x$ and join it with $(a,0)$ now imagine a square perpendicular to x-y plane. Do this for every single point on line $y=x$ from 0 to $a$. This will produce a pyramid with base area $a^2$ and height $a$. The volume of this pyramid will be $\frac{a^3}{3}$ which can be shown without employing integral. But now you will need to accept that sum of all cross-sectional areas of pyramid, in magnitude, is equal to its volume. But this approach is not extendable to all cases.